# Is there a word that means "lost thing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "lost thing"? Ir perhaps a word for "forgotten thing/ something that has been forgotten"? Similar to how *requirement* means "that which is required" or *necessity* is "something necessary"? I'm ideally looking for a noun or other words that are constructed to from an adjective describing something to the noun that stands for it.

Here are two sample sentences:

> - This book contains a list of major *[lost things]* throughout history.
> - The *[forgotten things]* inspire many mythological stories.

I am also okay if there's an archaic or uncommon word for this!

Comment: No noun that I can think of. As to adjectives, what's wrong with _lost, missing_ or _forgotten_?

Comment: First thought was *obscurity* / *obscurities*. It is more like "unrecognized" rather than "forgotten", but has a similar flavor.

Comment: In the first sample sentence, is there a requirement the item be *major*? Also, *lost* and *forgotten* are related but not synonymous.

Comment: The noun might be *losings*, but it's generally used in a gambling context (contrast *winnings*) and would probably just confuse.

Comment: An example of what you mean would be helpful. In what sense have they been lost to history?  Like a civilization that died out mysteriously, its buildings overgrown by jungle?

Comment: Do you mean physical objects that are lost/forgotten, or do you mean ideas/beliefs/practices?

Comment: It’s not out of the question to use *forgottens* (though I’d be tempted to put it in quotes). *Losses* doesn’t really work there, though. If you can use a phrase, maybe *casualties of time*.

Comment: Perhaps you could employ  *lagan* or the more familiar *flotsam*.

Comment: In and of itself, no. Quite separately, a lost thing could be the object of a search, so 'object/target/goal…' but those aren't what you want, are they?